# Issue deploying AzureFunctions to newly created AppService in the same ARM template

Tags: azure-functions, msdeploy, azure-rm-template

I'm working on an ARM template to deploy an azure function.  My steps are as follows

1) push arm template to blob storage and get the SAS uri 
2) push the azure functions to blob storage and get the SAS uri
3) run powershell command New-AzureRmResourceGroup   to create my new resource group
4) run  powershell command New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment  to deploy my application via an ARM template.

In my Arm template I'm using a nested template of MSDeploy to send up my azure function via a zip file.

The first deployment will create all of my resources but it will not deploy my Azure functions.

If I deploy  via the same process with the same arm template  to my freshly created resources and resource group, my azure functions will be deployed. I'm not sure what is going on with this process as both deployment are consider a success.

Here is my azure functions arm template with MSDeploy

```
{
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
        "name": "[variables('functionsName')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "kind": "functionapp",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms',variables('hostPlanName'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageName'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('appInsightsName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostPlanName'))]",
            "name": "[variables('functionsName')]"
        },
        "resources": [ 
            {
                "name": "MSDeploy",
                "type": "extensions",
                "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('functionsName'))]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "packageUri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'),  parameters('SampleFunctionAppPackageFolder'), '/', parameters('SampleFunctionAppPackageFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
                }
            },
            {
                "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
                "name": "appsettings",
                "type": "config",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionsName'))]",
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageName'))]",
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('functionsName'), '/Extensions/MSDeploy')]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                   ****  App settings removed *****
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: So what is the problem you're facing ?

Comment: The first deployment wont deploy the azure functions.  I want to try and make a fresh resources that have the azure functions deployed.

Comment: So you ve uploaded your code to a blob storage ?

Comment: yep. its in a zip file as it expects.  The uri is good too I have tested it and was able to download my functions zip file.  

Like stated in the questions. The 2nd deployment to the same resourcegroup will deploy the functions.   Just the first deployment does not deploy the functions for some reason

Comment: @Thomas   We were able to find a solution to this bug,  or I guess a work around

Comment: Good to know, you should post an answer if you think it would be useful for other people

Comment: oh for some reason I couldn't see post an answer button.  will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out having your appSettings in a different ARM template causes this issue of the azure functions not being deploying on the first run. Moving the AppSettings into the appFunction ARM template such as

```
"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
    "name": "[variables('functionsName')]",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "kind": "functionapp",
    "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms',variables('hostPlanName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostPlanName'))]",
        "name": "[variables('functionsName')]",
        "siteConfig": {
            "appSettings": [
                {
                    "name": "key1",
                    "value": "value1"
                }
            ]
        }
    }           
}
```

I was trying to avoid the deadlocking issue explained here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/hosamshobak/2016/05/26/arm-template-msdeploy-race-condition-issue/

but we saw this bug as a result of those steps. I haven't ran into this deadlocking issue while deploying but it still could be possible as I have no idea if the deadlocking issue has been fixed with MSDeploy.